# Wpf Dispatcher.BeginInvoke delegate issue

Tags: wpf, windows-phone

In my WP SignalR application I'm using this code:

```
_dataHub.Subscribe("ReceiveMessage").Received += list => App.RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Messages.Add(list[0].ToString()));
```

But I have to use similar code to subscribe to my SignalR server application.

I tried this one:

```
 _dataHub.Subscribe("ReceiveMessage").Received += list => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Messages.Add(list[0].ToString()));
```

I'm having delegate issue with that. Any help?

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: cannot convert lambda expression to type system.delegate because it is not a delegate type

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380996/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate-because-it-is-not-a-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in error you are providing lambda expression instead of delegate. Use **`Action`** like this:

```
_dataHub.Subscribe("ReceiveMessage").Received += list => 
             Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
                                         Messages.Add(list[0].ToString())));
```

Comment: I tried something like that but i must missed something :/ It solved my issue. Thanks!