# When use async method to open a form from another from it crashes C#

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

Im using a KinectV2 and Project Praga to interpretate gestures and do things like control the media, domotic, etc.

when my async method is triggered by a gesture, needs to open another form, but when it happens this second form crashes:

```
using Microsoft.Gestures;
using Microsoft.Gestures.Endpoint;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace UIControl
{
    public partial class KinectProject : Form
    {

        private static GesturesServiceEndpoint _gesturesService;
        private static Gesture _One;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Kinect Project Test";

        }

        public KinectProject()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e); InitializeGestures();
        }


        private async task InitializeGestures()
        {
            // One can optionally pass the hostname/IP address where the gestures service is hosted
            var gesturesServiceHostName = "localhost";
            await RegisterGestures(gesturesServiceHostName);
        }

        private static async Task RegisterGestures(string gesturesServiceHostName)
        {
            // Step 1: Connect to Microsoft Gestures service            
            _gesturesService = GesturesServiceEndpointFactory.Create(gesturesServiceHostName);
            await _gesturesService.ConnectAsync();

            // Step 2: Define bunch of custom Gestures, each detection of the gesture will emit some message into the console
            await RegisterOneGesture();

        }

        private static async Task RegisterOneGesture()
        {
            // Start with defining the first pose, ...
            var Iddle = new HandPose("iddle", new FingerPose(new AllFingersContext(), FingerFlexion.OpenStretched),
                                              new PalmPose(new AnyHandContext(), PoseDirection.Backward));

            var hold = new HandPose("Hold", new FingerPose(Finger.Index, FingerFlexion.Open, PoseDirection.Up),
                                            new FingerPose(new[] { Finger.Thumb, Finger.Middle, Finger.Ring, Finger.Pinky }, FingerFlexion.Folded),
                                            new PalmPose(new AnyHandContext(), PoseDirection.Backward));

            // ... finally define the gesture using the hand pose objects defined above forming a simple state machine: hold -> rotate
            _One = new Gesture("One", Iddle, hold);
            _One.Triggered += (s, e) => Executor(s);
            //_One.Triggered += (s, e) => OnGestureDetected(s, e, ConsoleColor.DarkRed);

            // Step 3: Register the gesture             
            // Registering the like gesture _globally_ (i.e. isGlobal:true), by global registration we mean this gesture will be 
            // detected even it was initiated not by this application or if the this application isn't in focus
            await _gesturesService.RegisterGesture(_One, isGlobal: true);
        }

        private static void OnGestureDetected(object sender, GestureSegmentTriggeredEventArgs args, ConsoleColor foregroundColor)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("Gesture detected! : ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = foregroundColor;
            Console.WriteLine(args.GestureSegment.Name);

            Console.ResetColor();

        }
        
        static void Executor(object sender, GestureSegmentTriggeredEventArgs args, ConsoleColor foregroundColor)
        {
            MusicForm V1 = new MusicForm();
            V1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I recently add the override method but is the same, when MusicForm Opens it crashes, but if i use a button instead the MusicForm opens correctly

[Edit]
i add this to `Executor` and fix `OnLoad()`

```
protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
         base.OnLoad(e);
         await InitializeGestures();
    }


private void Executor(object sender)
    {
          int managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        MessageBox.Show("ManagedThreadId = " + managedThreadId);

        if (this.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // If the handle is not yet created, create it
            CreateHandle();
        }
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate
        {
            MusicForm V1 = new MusicForm();
            V1.Show();
        }));
```

and `ManagedThreadId` returned `ManagedThreadId = 6`

Comment: "when my async method is triggered " which one? You should also reformat your code to be easier to read (extraneous whitespace, etc). Be specific on the error, where it is happening, what it is (crashes is a bit vague).

Comment: When i trigger RegisterOneGesture (idk how mark as code here in comments) it calls Executor and open MusicForm but MusicForm crashes
@gilliduck
i try to fix the blanc spaces in the code, sorry i delete a big part of code because is commented

Comment: You need to make sure, the form is created and Show() is called both on the UI thread. That may not be the case, here. So, if not: Marshall to the UI thread.

Comment: My form is Created, and Show calls to it and opens but crashes, how can i marshal to de UI? @Fildor

Comment: First thing, make `OnLoad()` async and await `InitializeGestures()` -- I don't know whether the `Triggered` event is raised in a secondary Thread. You can verify this by checking [ManagedThreadID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid) in the `Executor()` method. If it's not `1`, then you have to `BeginInvoke()` the `Executor()` method (don't use the synchronous `Invoke` counterpart). You're passing EventArgs to this method, but it's not clear whether this object is used for something and, if it is, whether it allows safe cross-thread operations.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your help, i fix ````OnLoad()```` and try to use ````BeginInvoke()```` because   ````ManagedThreadID```` returns me ````6````
But now the app can't open ````MusicForm```` and if i try to trigger ````Executor```` more than 1 time The ````MusicForm````  open crashed(not responding) again[only this form, my ````MainForm```` runs perfectly in background]

Comment: `InitializeGestures()` needs to be `async Task` as the other methods. With *`BeginInvoke()` the `Executor()` method* I meant: `_One.Triggered += (s, e) => BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Executor(s) ));` -- Now, your `Executor()` of course is not real code, since you're passing `(s)`, but that method expects other parameters, so it wouldn't compile. As mentioned, I don't know, in real code, what these other parameters are for and whether any of these can be used cross-thread. You'd have to show what exactly happen after `MusicForm` is shown -- `KinectProject`'s Handle cannot be `IntPtr.Zero` here

Comment: As a note, never (ever) use a MessagerBox to show values when some threading stuff is going on. Just write to the Output Pane of Visual Studio (i.e., use `Console.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine("")`, depending on your configuration)

Comment: i try to use Executor like you said but it returns this error:
https://ibb.co/RY7N72P

Comment: That's because, as already mentioned, you have not posted real code (the code you actually have there). In the code you have posted here, the compiler would know that `BeginInvoke()` is a method of the Form. In your actual code, the Form reference is missing, so it doesn't know what object you're talking about when you write `BeginInvoke()`

Comment: here you can see the error: https://ibb.co/WBBRwkm in task manager,
for now i use this:  ````_instance = this;```` where my ````InicializeComponent();```` is
and in ````_One.triggered````  i do this ````_One.Triggered += (s, e) =>  _instance.Executor(s,e); ```` my code doesnt have error but the same crash in ````MusicForm```` (My music form is already empty, i have all the code in another form[inside other proyect] but having the same problem if i call it from my main form)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the UI thread for these kind of operations.
You can use invoke or begininvoke.
Try to change your executor in

```
    this.Invoke(() =>
    {
        MusicForm V1 = new MusicForm();
        V1.Show();
    });
```

Comment: i do this:
```private void Executor(object sender, GestureSegmentTriggeredEventArgs args, ConsoleColor foregroundColor){this.Invoke(() =>{MusicForm V1 = new MusicForm();V1.Show();
});```

but it says me that cannot convert lambda expresion to type 'Delegate'

Comment: this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380996/cannot-convert-lambda-expression-to-type-system-delegate-because-it-is-not-a-d try to cast it to action and it should work. However when you want to interact with any Control class object from a non UI thread you need to use the Invoke or BeginInvoke method. You can also check if the invoke is required with InvokeRequired property.

Comment: I try to use ```this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
            {MusicForm V1 = new MusicForm(); V1.Show();});```
But is the same thing, cannot change from lambda to delegate

this line is in conflict:
```_One.Triggered += (s, e) => Executor(s, e, ConsoleColor.DarkRed);```

Comment: I have the same problem, you dont know how to fix it? @filtrow

Comment: Try to reproduce the error with a minimum example that i can run.

Comment: Is very dificult bc, the Kinect uses the infrared camera and Praga Project(is an outdated framework from microsoft) interprets the gestures....
Rn my main problem is when i do a gesture and Praga project trigger ````RegisterOneGesture```` my ````MusicForm```` loads "Not Responding" in task manager and my ````MainForm```` is running normaly maybe i can record a video showing the error